# Unable to get preview of a msg file from SharePoint REST API

Tags: search, spfx, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx-webparts, search-query

How can I get preview URL of a msg file? I’m developing a custom search web part in SPFx framework.

My code:

```
Const sp = spfi(“https://home.sharepoint.com/sites/site/").using(SPFx(this.props.context));
var propResults: any[];
const searcQuery: ISearchQuery = {
SortList:[{Property: “Created”,Direction: SortDirection.Descending}],
RowLimit: 50,
EnablePhonetic:true,
HiddenConstraints:”IsDocuments:true”,
SelectProperties:[ "FileName","FileType","Path","Author","Created","CustMyPagesOWSBOOL","IsDocument","PictureThumbnailURL","ServerRedirectedEmbedURL"];
}
const sq  = SearchQueryBuilder(searchValue,searchQuery);
Sp.search(sq).then((result:searchResults) => {
  Bla,bla code 
}
```

returning: preview for pdf, word excel from the `ServerRedirectedEmbedURL` field, but if the file is `.msg` it returns ServerRedirectedEmbedURL.KeyID: hash
Not `"https://home.sharepoint.com/sites/site/library/Forms/AllItems.aspx?sortField=Modified&isAscending=false&id=%2Fsites%2Fcust001%2F1205733229%2Flibrary%2FUpps%C3%B6gn%20kt%201205733229Test6%2D13435973%2Emsg&viewid=6ef45ae4%2D733b%2D4ae8%2Db872%2Dd82bf07b78cb&parent=%2Fsites%2Fcust001%2F1205733229%2Flibrary"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use itempreview in microsoft graph to get preview of a email saved in sharepoint.